# Can I change the color of the status bar in iOS8 with scrolling?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I'm a UI designer with really no XCode experience, but I want to ask this before I design something outlandish to hand to my iOS developers.

Essentially I am wondering if it's possible to change the status bar text and background color when a user does a drag gesture (scrolling). I'd like it to change from a [black text, transparent background] to a [white text, black background] when the user scrolls through content.

(We're building for iOS8 exclusively, if that helps.)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The status bar has no "background" - it is transparent. So the question makes no sense.

Comment: I know that a transparent background is possible, but I'm also asking it to change from a black text to white text via a scroll. Do you happen to know if that's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the text color of the status bar by setting the barStyle of navigationBar. UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent will give white status bar text  and UIBarStyleDefault will give black status bar text. You can change the navigation bar color by setting the property barTintColor.

This properties can be changed, when the user scrolls through ie. a tableview.